# What characters are allowed in wsdl name attribute?

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl that contains the following complex type:

```
<complexType name="OUTGROUP">
    <sequence>
        <element name="NUMBER#" type="xsd:decimal" />
        <element name="DOLLAR$" type="xsd:decimal" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

I was wondering what is the valid set of characters for the `name` attribute? Is is valid to have a `#` and `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not valid for the value associated with the name attribute in a WSDL to contain the "#" or "$" characters. This rule is enforced because a valid WSDL must follow the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` schema.

The valid characters can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Letter)

Answer (score 0):

The XML you posted is a fragment of an XML Schema. It is XML schema that restricts the naming, and it restricts it based on what's valid in an XML document. The reason you can't have "#" and "$" in the schema is because you can't have those in an XML element or attribute name.

---

#### EDIT

XML Schema describes a valid XML document. You cannot have those characters in the `name` attribute of an `element` element because that would permit an XML document to be validated which contains those invalid characters.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question, I wasn't asking if you could have "#" and "$" in the element or attribute name. I was asking if you could in have them in the associated values.

Comment: This is a completely valid XML document:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root>
<root>
  <node id="FOO#" />
</root>`

Comment: The following is not: `<root><NUMBER#>1.0</NUMBER#><DOLLAR$>2.0</DOLLAR$></root>`

Comment: I may have improperly phrased my question but if you look at the example that is not what I was asking.